# Is it possible to load a TextureResource (RealityKit) from a PHAsset (PhotoKit) without having to first write it to the app documents directory?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit, photokit

TextureResource only takes a URL to load a texture from an image. It won't accept image NSData directly.

PHImageManager will not give you a direct URL for an image, it allows you to get image data for PHAssets. ([This snippet][1] that you see if you google the issue doesn't work anymore, and was a hack when it did work)

So the only way I've been able to render the photo roll in RealityKit is by fetching the image data from PhotoKit, writing images to a url in the application docs dir, and then giving that url to RealityKit. It works, but it doesn't perform awesome and seems really wasteful. Is there a way to do this without having to cache the data inbetween?

Some gifs for context:
https://github.com/brucedaniel/PhotoGlobeAR/raw/main/demo2.gif
https://github.com/brucedaniel/PhotoGlobeAR/raw/main/demo1.gif

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the part where you can load the `TextureResource` directly from data, as getting the data should not be an issue.

iOS 15.0+

```
let image: CGImage = UIImage(data: data, scale: 1)!.cgImage!
// or 
// let image: CGImage = .init(jpegDataProviderSource: .init(data: data as CFData)!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: false, intent: .defaultIntent)!
let texture: TextureResource = try? .generate(from: image, withName: "someName", options: .init(semantic: .hdrColor))
```